# calling VBA forms from a button in Excel

Tags: excel, forms, vba

I have a macro that parses through a large file in Excel.  I created a form that allows me to search for and provide a summary of specific messages.  I can put

```
FormName.Show
```

at the end of the macro and it works.  The form displays as the parsing macro completes.  But I don't always want the form to appear and sometimes I want to call it again after I've saved the spreadsheet.  So I wrote another function that can create a button that can open the form.  In the .OnAction statement I have OnAction = "FormName.Show"

```
Sub Create_Button()
ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(437.25, 72, 125.25, 47.25).Select
Selection.OnAction = "FormName.Show"
Selection.Characters.Text = "Search Messages"
End Sub
```

This doesn't work, it created the button but when I click on the button I get

"Cannot run the macro "xxxx.xlam'!FormName.Show'  The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled.

Why does it work in the main macro but not in the button OnAction?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834436.aspx), `Shape.OnAction` requires a macro name, not VBA code.  You have tried to pass it VBA code.  Instead try this:

```
Selection.OnAction = "showForm"
....
End Sub

Public Sub showForm()
     FormName.Show
End Sub
```

Comment: No problem.  Consider marking one of the answers as the answer if they solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

`.OnAction` will not only run Macros not it will not evaluate code.  Paste thiss in a standard module.

---

```
Sub ShowUserform()
    FormName.Show
End Sub

Sub Create_Button()
    With ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(437.25, 72, 125.25, 47.25)
        .OnAction = "ShowUserform"
        .Characters.Text = "Search Messages"
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]